# настройка PHPStorm для работы с GitLab по SSH

Tags: phpstorm, ssh, gitlab

Запущен PuTTY-агент, сгенерированы ключи.Проверка `plink.exe -v -ssh git@gitlab.foo.com` проходит успешно.
Как настроить PHPStorm чтобы он заработал через ключ SSH ?

Comment: Какая операционна система? На линуксе и макос нужно просто в .ssh положить ключи и все заработает

Comment: @Krya PUTTY, значит, Windows.

Comment: В чем проблема то? Вы вообще пытались что-то настроить в phpstorm? Создайте новый проект "get from version control", укажите данные. Phpstrom потом спросит про данные. Если ключ авторизован в админке GitLab к проекту или к учетной записи, то автоматом подхватится. Есть еще галочка в settings - version control - github - "clone git repositories useng ssh"

Comment: А зачем хамить? Если бы не пытался, то не спрашивал бы! Когда я ввожу данные гита, он запрашивает логин и пароль. Ввожу, но он выдает что они неверные. При этом другие клиенты для работы с гитом без проблем коннектятся и клонируют проект